# How to cypher query a neo4j DB with WHERE clause on sparse property

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have Nodes in my Neo4j database that have certain properties that do not exist on all nodes, but I want to query against those properties with Cypher with a WHERE clause.

Example Data:

```
{id:"52", name:"Jim", age:"32", gender:"M"}
{id:"55", name:"Lisa", age:"22", gender:"F"}
{id:"97", name:"Chris", age:"38"}
```

Now, if I want to run a Cypher query on gender, it gives me an error on the Chris record, stating that the gender property does not exist on that node.

Example Cypher query:

```
START n=NODE(*) WHERE n.gender="M" RETURN n;
```

The specific error message I am getting is:

```
EntityNotFoundException: The property 'gender' does not exist on Node[4925]
```

I am running version 1.9.2 of Neo4j.  I'd like to upgrade to 2.x and try to use labels and auto_indexes galore.  But, I'm not in a position go move away from the stable release yet.

Any way to solve this with Cypher query, or with 1.9.2 indexing features?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
WHERE n.gender! = "M"
```

or

```
WHERE has(n.gender) AND n.gender = "M"
```

Comment: and btw, that syntax is no longer necessary in 2.0 M05+

Comment: The has() AND... syntax worked like a charm.  Thanks!