# neo4j query for nullable property

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I am using spring-neo4j. I have an entity called User with properties (username, firstName, lastName) and firstName and lastName are optional properties.

Now I want to implement a user search query which will search across all three properties.

```
@Query(value = "start user=node:__types__(className='com.xxx.entity.User') where user.username =~ {0} or user.firstName =~ {0} or user.lastName =~ {0} return user")
List<User> searchByName(String keyword);
```

The query fails saying that:

```
The property 'firstName' does not exist on Node[21].
```

However, if I search only on username, it gives me the result. I tried using the ? operator for nullable properties:

```
 @Query(value = "start user=node:__types__(className='com.xxx.entity.User') where user.username =~ {0} or user.firstName? =~ {0} or user.lastName? =~ {0} return user")
 List<User> searchByName(String keyword);
```

But this will fetch me all the nodes where firstName or lastName are missing.

Any idea how do I implement this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would

```
start user=node:__types__(className='com.xxx.entity.User') 
where user.username =~ {0} 
  or (has(user.firstName) and user.firstName =~ {0}) 
  or (has(user.lastName) and user.lastName =~ {0}) 
return user
```

work?

**Edit:**

There are many reasons for a query not to return data. If you want help with that, share sample data and the parameters you are passing with your query. Use [Neo4j console](http://console.neo4j.org) to share data and put the link and parameter examples in your question.

Until then, this might be helpful:

Use `!` instead of `?`.

***[--verbose]***
In Neo4j 1.x you can indeed use the `?` and `!` syntax, but you are using them wrong. `?` defaults to true when the property is missing, which means your query matches the nodes you want plus all nodes that don't have a `firstName` or that don't have a `lastName`. `!` will default to false when the property is missing and therefore exclude those nodes. `n.prop! = val` is equivalent to the `has(n.prop) and n.prop=val` I used above. See [Neo4j stable docs](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/query-where.html#where-default-true-if-property-is-missing).

In Neo4j 2.0+ the `!?` syntax is removed. Non-existing properties default to `null`. Therefore `n.prop=val` will evaluate to false exactly when `has(n.prop)` does(*). This means that your original query would work in 2.0–the query would resolve a missing property as a non-match and it would neither break nor include all nodes that don't have `firstName` or `lastName`(**). See [Neo4j milestone docs](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/query-where.html#where-default-to-true-if-property-is-missing). You might as well use syntax that won't break when SpringDataNeo4j moves to Neo4j 2.0, so use `has(n.prop) and n.prop=val` which works on either version.

Also please see [How to cypher query a neo4j DB with WHERE clause on sparse property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19311926/how-to-cypher-query-a-neo4j-db-with-where-clause-on-sparse-property).

(*)(except it won't if `val=null`)
(**)(unless you pass `null` as a parameter)

Comment: This query doesn't give any error but it doesn't fetch me any results.